# Best way to insert items from a Derived class's constructor into a Base class's private std::vector?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

I have these classes:

```
class Base
{
...
private:
std::vector<X> v;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
Derived(X*, int n);
};
```

where the constructor of Derived is passed an array of item Xs, which I need to insert into my vector v in the Base class. (X is a smart pointer)

Currently I see two ways to do this:

1. Create a function in Base:
   InsertItem(X*) that will insert an
   item into the vector (1 by 1)
2. Create a vector in Derived that contains the
   full list, then get it into Base by
   moving the entire vector.

I dont see any advantages to #2, but was wondering if #1 was a good solution, or if there are better ways to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the array `Derived` gets dynamic? Also I assume `Derived` is meant to derive from `Base`. (And has a missing semicolon :])

Comment: Fixed the semicolon =p. 

I had wanted to try to stop using protected - I have been entirely abusing it with my other classes... Plus, I just picked up Effective C++!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a third option if you can modify `Base`.  You could make the vector `protected` which will allow base classes full access:

```
class Base
{
...
protected:
    std::vector<X> v;
};
```

Your base class can now directly operate on `v`.  If you need to expose much of the vector functionality to `Derived`, this is the easiest way.

If not, I would just add the one function (i.e. option #1) and would make it protected:

```
class Base
{
...

protected:
    void push_back(const X &x)
    {
        v.push_back(x);
    }

private:
    std::vector<X> v;
};
```

Comment: Changing from `private` to `protected` is so obvious, I would just assume there are reasons it can't be done. And isn't your other suggestion just a repeat of item 1. in the question?

Comment: Yes, my second suggestion is just a repeat of #1 - the idea was if he didn't like protected, my advice would be to prefer #1 over #2.

Comment: I've currently got it implemented as #1. Thanks for reminding me to use a const reference.

Comment: I don't like the first option, `push_back` is much better from an encapsulation point of view.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to create a (public or protected) constructor in base that will take the parameters and populate the vector directly. No intermediate vectors need be created or passed around.

```
class Base
{
 . . .
protected:
    Base(X* x,int n);
 . . .
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    Derived(X* xes, int n):Base(xes,n){};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can, I would create a `protected` constructor in `Base` that accepts the `X*` argument just like the `Derived` constructor, and then in `Derived`'s constructor initialization list, pass the argument to `Base`'s protected constructor and have it do the actual insertion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the container in the base class to remain private, you might consider adding a public (or protected) function in `Base` to allow the derived class to add a range.  This way, the `Base` container type can be encapsulated (`Derived` doesn't need to know it's a `vector`), and `Derived` can still pass the whole thing down in one shot:

```
class Base
{
...
private:
    std::vector<X> v;

protected
    template <class iterator_t>
    void assign( iterator_t first, iterator_t last) {
        v.assign( first, last);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
Derived(X* p, int n) {
    Base::assign( p, p+n);
}
};
```

It's not much of an encapsulation, but the container could be changed with a changing the derived class, and a derived class could easily be written that takes data in a form different than an array, if desired. And [as zdan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588803/best-way-to-insert-items-from-a-derived-classs-constructor-into-a-base-classs-p/2588865#2588865) this functionality could be part of public or protected constructor for `Base` if that makes more sense (which is likely).

The idea of using iterator ranges to represent the content or subset of a container is widespread in the STL.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the member variable to be `protected` so that classes that inherit `Base` can access it.  Alternatively keep the member variable private but add a `protected` accessor method to allow classes that inherit `base` to add to the vector etc

Comment: No, that's a breach of encapsulation. Better to provide full fledged methods.